# checkout a repository ON the remote?

Tags: git

so my situation is:

- i have a server that i can ssh into. a remote repository (`git init --bare`) exists here
- i have multiple people with local repositories on their machine, connected to this remote repository
- i *need* to use the server to host the files of the `main` branch of the repostory

therefore, i am looking for a command to tell git to checkout a branch *of* the remote repository *onto* the remote (so this is local, in the server's perspective). i've tried just normal checking out, but it seems git requires a working directory which isn't available the way the remote repository was initialized. how can i achieve this?

Comment: clone the bare repo into a different location as a non-bare repo.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was going to say. :) Just `cd` into another spot on the server and say `git clone <remoteRepo>`. This will automatically checkout `main` so you're all set.

Comment: ah, so would i would need to re-clone every time `main` is updated, right?

Comment: Nope. From then on you would just pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it exactly the same way you would do it if you were hosting the files of `main` on a *different* machine. Just `cd` into a free spot on the server and say `git clone <remoteRepo>`. This will automatically checkout `main` so you're all set. And from now on, you just `git pull` from time to time to bring those files up to date.